# Finding polygons within a certain radius of a number of other polygons

Tags: postgis

I have a table with a bunch of polygons (or multipolygons, I'm not sure...does it matter?) of one type (A) defined in a CTE, and then another of another type (B) in another CTE. I want to filter for just type A polygons that are within a given radius of *any* of the polygons of type B. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a collection of your 'B' polygons using **ST_Collect** & then use a WHERE clause with **ST_DWithin** to specify your distance parameter.

For example:

```
WITH polys_a AS (
  SELECT geom
  FROM buildings_dc
),
polys_b AS (
  SELECT geom
  FROM buildings_va
)
SELECT polys_a.*
FROM polys_a,
(
        SELECT ST_Collect(geom) as geoms
        FROM polys_b
) as c
WHERE ST_DWithin(a.geom, c.geoms, .001);
```

Note that both sets of geometries may be of different types (e.g. Polygon, Point, MultiPolygon, etc.), but they must be of the same projection/ coordinate system. If you are using standard WGS84 (SRID 4326), the distance parameter is in terms of degrees.